# WinForms DataGridView re-painting problem

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How can I stop a DataGridView from re-painting the whole grid when a new row is added? 
Can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if `SuspendLayout`/`ResumeLayout` would help with this. It's really for control layout but might be worth trying since it's quick and easy.

Otherwise the way to be able to control this would be to make it virtual (set `VirtualMode` to true). [How to: Implement Virtual Mode in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2b177d6d.aspx)

And here's a step by step walkthrough: [Implementing Virtual Mode in the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15a31akc.aspx)

Comment: You've actually managed to successfully get closer to my specific problem. If you use virtual mode, you'll notice that whenever the RowCount is set (and rows are added/removed from the grid), the currently visible cells are re-painted. This is behavior I would like to avoid under certain conditions. 

I'd assume that the grid gets invalidated due to rows being added/removed, causing all visible cells to become invalidated as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you place the grid in an update panel it will repaint but no screen refresh.

```
     <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1" >
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DataGrid ID="DataGrid1" runat="server">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="SomeColumn1" DataField="SomeColumn1" />
                    <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="SomeColumn2" DataField="SomeColumn2" />
                    <asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="SomeColumn3" DataField="SomeColumn3" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:DataGrid>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DataGrid1" />
        </Triggers>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: This should be a comment, or explain how to put the grid in an update panel with a code sample.

Comment: @KH1229 Please elaborate your answer.